# how to redirect or call routerlink in ts file in angular2

Tags: angular

This is angular 2 routing code

```
     <nav>
         <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active">Step I</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"> <a routerLink="/faculty" routerLinkActive="active">Step II</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a routerLink="/heroes" routerLinkActive="active">Step III</a></li>
        </ul>          
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

button click event

```
clickFunctionEvent(value: any) {
       this.dataService.setFacultyAnswer(JSON.stringify(value)).subscribe(
      tradeshows => {    
        this.data= tradeshows 
        //if data=success then redirect to next routerLink like "/faculty"                  
       },
      error => {console.error('QuestionList:\n\t ' + error);}
    );
}
```

if `data=success` then redirect to next routerLink like `"/faculty"`

so how to it in `.ts` file

And `how to disable previous routerLink so not allow to go back`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 61, accepted):

you use

```
 //in your constructor
  constructor(public router: Router){}

//navigation link.
 this.router.navigate(['your-route']);
```

Comment: Please share documentation link as well

Comment: import statement as follows `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

Comment: Highly needed @eohdev

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['your-route']);` needs to be inside a function

Comment: how can i add a parameter to my route using this method?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your .ts file and first import `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`
and then change the constructor to this

```
constructor(public router:Router)
{

}
```

and then add route link as:

```
this.router.navigate(['your-desired-route-name']);
```